# Таймер обратного отсчета python + tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, таймер

Ребята, нужна помощь с реализацией таймера обратного отсчета, реализованный именно на питоне + ткинтер. Функционал: 1 кнопка старт - запуск отсчета; 2- кнопка рестарт- для сброса положения таймера в изначальное положение(2 мин 00 сек); 3(или 3 и 4) - вывод данных на экран. Начальная позиция -2 минуты.
Сегодня, впервые столкнулся с Ткинтером и уже кругом голова. Вот что набросал

```
from tkinter import *

import time

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master= None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.minutes = IntVar()
        self.l_min = Label(self,font=('Helvetica',24))
        self.l_min.pack(side='top')
        self.l_min['textvariable'] = self.minutes

        self.seconds = IntVar()
        self.l_sec = Label(self, font=('Helvetica', 24))
        self.l_sec.pack(side='top')
        self.l_sec['textvariable'] = self.seconds

        self.b_start = Button(self, text ='START',fg='red')
        self.b_start.bind('<Button-1>', self.start_timer)
        self.b_start.pack(side= 'bottom')

        self.b_restart = Button(self, text ="RESTART", fg='blue')
       # self.b_restart.bind('<Button-1>',reset_timer)
        self.b_restart.pack(side= 'bottom')
    def start_timer(self,mins):
        for mins in range(1,-1,-1):
            self.minutes.set(mins)
            for secs in range(59,-1,-1):
                self.seconds.set(secs)
                time.sleep(1)

    def reset_timer(self):
        pass

root= Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
root.mainloop()
```

Буду благодарен за помощь или намёк. З.Ы. Похожих тем много но только под javascript или другие ЯП.

Comment: Но проблема-то в чем? Исключения какие-нибудь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

timer_running = False  # запущен ли таймер
default_seconds = 120  # изначальное положение(2 мин 00 сек)
timer_seconds = default_seconds  # текущее положение таймера, сек

def timer_start_pause():
    global timer_running
    timer_running = not timer_running  # работа или пауза
    if timer_running:  # работа
        timer_tick()

def timer_reset():
    global timer_running, timer_seconds
    timer_running = False  # стоп
    timer_seconds = default_seconds  # изначальное положение
    show_timer()

def timer_tick():
    if timer_running and timer_seconds:
        label.after(1000, timer_tick)  # перезапустить через 1 сек
        # уменьшить таймер
        global timer_seconds
        timer_seconds -= 1
        show_timer()

def show_timer():
    '''отобразить таймер'''
    m = timer_seconds//60
    s = timer_seconds-m*60
    label['text'] = '%02d:%02d' % (m, s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    label = Label(root)
    label.pack()
    Button(root, text='start/pause', command=timer_start_pause).pack()  # запуск/пауза отсчета
    Button(root, text='reset', command=timer_reset).pack()  # сброс

    timer_reset()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

class CountdownTimer(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.label_mins = tk.Label(self, text="2",  bg ="white")
        self.label_mins.grid(row=1,column=2 )
        self.label_secs = tk.Label(self, text="0",  bg ="white")
        self.label_secs.grid(row=1, column = 3)

        self.rem_seconds = 59
        self.rem_minutes = 1
        self.stop_marker = False
        self.b_start=tk.Button(self, text="START",command = self.start_countdown)
        self.b_start.grid(row = 2, column= 2, sticky = "S")
        self.b_reset = tk.Button(self, text="RESET", command = self.reset_countdown)
        self.b_reset.grid(row = 2, column =3, sticky = "S")
        self.b_stop = tk.Button(self, text="STOP", command = self.stop_countdown)
        self.b_stop.grid(row=2, column = 4, sticky = "S")
    def start_countdown(self):

        if self.stop_marker!=True:
            if self.rem_seconds==0 and self.rem_minutes==0:
                self.label_mins.configure(text="Time")
                self.label_secs.configure(text= "is up !!!")
            elif self.rem_seconds<0:
                self.rem_minutes-=1
                self.rem_seconds =59
                self.start_countdown()
            else:
                self.label_mins.configure(text = "%d"%self.rem_minutes)
                self.label_secs.configure(text = "%d"%self.rem_seconds)
                self.rem_seconds -= 1
                self.after(1000,self.start_countdown)

    def stop_countdown(self):
        self.stop_marker = True

    def reset_countdown(self):
        self.label_mins.configure(text = "2")
        self.label_secs.configure(text = "0")
        self.rem_minutes = 1
        self.rem_seconds = 59
        self.stop_marker = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CountdownTimer()
    app.mainloop()
```

Вот что у меня получилось, правда со своими "велосипедами". А проблема заключалась в том что я использовал time.sleep().